# Desordenar array y añadir datos a otro array

Tags: javascript, array

No se porque no funciona, lo estoy probando con ejemplos más pequeños y funciona pero cuando lo aplico a este no funciona.

Intento que coja un dato aleatorio del array numeros, y lo ponga dentro de arrayDesordenado, al buscar el aleatorio tiene que comparar primero que este no esté ya dentro para que no entren repetidos.

```
var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
var numerosDesordenados = [];

function numAleatorio(inferior, superior){
var numPosibilidades = superior - inferior
var aleat = Math.random() * numPosibilidades
aleat = Math.round(aleat)
return parseInt(inferior) + aleat
}

function barajar(){
for(var i=0; i<numeros.length; i++) {
    var num = numAleatorio(1,numeros.length);
    if(numerosDesordenados.indexOf(numeros[num]) >= 0) {
        i = i-1;
    } else {
        numerosDesordenados[i] = numeros[num];
    }
  }
}

for(var i=0; i<numerosDesordenados.length; i++) {
document.write(numerosDesordenados[i] + "<br>");
```

}

Comment: Entonces, ¿hay un problema o no?

Comment: Lo he solucionado, pues no llamaba a la función por eso no funcionaba, he publicado al solución

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta, puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que optaría por un **while** en la función **barajar**.

```js
function barajar(){
    var size = numeros.length, superior = size-1, num;
    while(size--) {
        num = numeros[numAleatorio(0, superior)];
        (numerosDesordenados.indexOf(num) < 0) ? (numerosDesordenados[size] = num) : size++;
    }
}
```

De todas formas cualquier versión basada en una aproximación del [Algoritmo Fisher-Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates) sería una opción válida. De echo Yo tengo alguna función de este tipo en la que te permite limitar el número máximo de coincidencias.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo otra alternativa, en tu caso los **números** se quitan desde una posición **aleatoria**, pero en mi caso los números se quitan del principio y se insertan en una posición aleatoria, pero de todas formas el resultado es que está **desordenado**.

Estoy usando las funciones que ya vienen con javascript, `Math.floor`, `Math.random`, `concat`, `slice` y `shift`.

- Función `Math.floor`: Redondea para abajo.
- Método `concat`: Concatena el `array` con otro.
- Otro método llamado `slice`: Secciona el *array* en las posiciones dadas.
- El `shift` sirve para extraer el primer elemento del *array*.

Como se puede ver en el siguiente código no hay `for` ni `if`, solo un `while` con un `break` que aparece si se queda sin `length` (longitud).

```
function desordenar(numeros)
{
    var desordenado = []
    while(true)
    {
        if(!numeros.length){break}
        var sacado = numeros.shift()
        var aleatorio=Math.floor(Math.random()*(desordenado.length+1))
        var inicio = desordenado.slice(0,aleatorio)
        var medio = sacado
        var fin = desordenado.slice(aleatorio,desordenado.length)
        desordenado = (inicio).concat(medio).concat(fin)
    }
    return desordenado
}
var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
desordenar(numeros)
```

Answer (score -1):

Me acabo de dar cuenta de que si no uso la funcion barajar() obviamente no funcionará XD

SOLUCIONADO

```
barajar();
for(var i=0; i<numerosDesordenados.length; i++) {
  document.write(numerosDesordenados[i] + "<br>");
}
```